# glDrawElements() only draws first two faces

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

**SOLVED. Solution to problem:** `attribStride` was not set correctly.

I am writing a small Google Cardboard app which can load and render any Wavefront .obj file with its material propertys of the surface in the linked .mtl file. For rendering I am using a VBO and IBO. For the material propertys of the surface and lightning I am using phong shading.

My problem is, that `glDrawElements()` will only render the first two triangles of a cube, which is made of 12 triangles.

- All triangles which form the cube are set up counter clockwise.
- The vertex array and index array data which are generated by parsing the .obj file are valid.
- The data and lengths of the client side FloatBuffer for the VBO and client side ShortBuffer for the IBO are valid.
- The lengths of the VBO and IBO set up by `glBufferData()` are valid.
- The shaders are compiled and attached correctly.
- All attribute and uniform locations set up by `glGetAttribLocation()` and `glGetUniformLocation()` for the shaders are valid.

I have checked these points in the Debugger and logcat.
I realize that its a lot of code. But I couldn't find the problem or the answer to my problem anywhere. So please please help :D And thanks in the first place :)

This method sets up the VBO, IBO, shader program, shader program locations, textures and shader program uniform values:

```
private void initializeGL() {
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL()");

    // Set camera matrix.
    Matrix.setLookAtM(camera, OFFSET, EYE_POINT_X, EYE_POINT_Y, EYE_POINT_Z, CENTER_OF_VIEW_X, CENTER_OF_VIEW_Y, CENTER_OF_VIEW_Z, UP_VECTOR_X, UP_VECTOR_Y, UP_VECTOR_Z);

    // Initialize shader program.
    shaderProgram.init();
    shaderProgramHandle = shaderProgram.getProgramHandle();

    // Initialize object information.
    objectInformation.init();

    vboHandle = objectInformation.getVbo().getVboHandle();
    vboLength = objectInformation.getVbo().getVboLength();

    iboHandle = objectInformation.getIbo().getIboHandle();
    iboLength = objectInformation.getIbo().getIboLength();

    uniforms = objectInformation.getUniformArray();
    numOfUniforms = objectInformation.getNumOfUniforms();
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): Number of uniforms = " + numOfUniforms);

    textures = objectInformation.getTextureArray();
    numOfTextures = objectInformation.getNumOfTextures();
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): Number of textures = " + numOfTextures);

    // Get vertex shader uniform locations.
    modelViewProjectionParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "u_ModelViewProjection");
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): modelViewProjectionParam = " + modelViewProjectionParam);

    modelViewParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "u_ModelView");
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): modelViewParam = " + modelViewParam);

    normalMatrixParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "u_NormalMatrix");
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): normalMatrixParam = " + normalMatrixParam);

    // Get vertex shader attribute locations.
    positionParam = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "a_Position");
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): positionParam = " + positionParam);
    if(boolTexCoords) {
        attribStride += 4 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
        texCoordParam = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "a_TexCoord");
        Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): texCoordParam = " + texCoordParam);
    }
    normalParam = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "a_Normal");
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): normalParam = " + normalParam);

    // Get fragment shader phong uniform locations.
    if(boolPhongLightning) {
        lightPosParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "lightPosition");
        Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): lightPosParam = " + lightPosParam);
        IaParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "Ia");
        Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): IaParam = " + IaParam);
        IpParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "Ip");
        Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): IpParam = " + IpParam);
    }

    // Set fragment shader material uniforms.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramHandle);

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfUniforms; i++) {
        String unifName = uniforms[i].getUnifName();
        location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, unifName);
        checkGLError(TAG, "initializeGL(): " + unifName + " shader location");

        vec = uniforms[i].getArray();
        if(vec != null) {
            GLES20.glUniform3fv(location, 1, vec, 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): " + unifName + "_Param = " + location);
        } else {
            float value = uniforms[i].getValue();
            GLES20.glUniform1f(location, value);
            Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): " + unifName + "_Param = " + location);
        }
    }

    // Set fragment shader phong uniforms.
    if(boolPhongLightning) {
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(IaParam, 1, Ia, 0);
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(IpParam, 1, Ip, 0);
    }

    // Set fragment shader textures.
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfTextures; i++) {
        // Set active texture unit.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + i);

        // Bind texture to active texture unit.
        int texHandle = textures[i].getTextureHandle();
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle);

        // Assign texture unit to uniform in fragment shader.
        String unifName = textures[i].getUnifName();
        location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, unifName);

        GLES20.glUniform1i(location, i);
        checkGLError(TAG, "initializeGL(): glUniform1i()");
        Log.i(TAG, "initializeGL(): " + unifName + "Param = " + location);
    }

    GLES20.glUseProgram(0);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LESS);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);
    GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.1f);
}
```

public void onDrawEye():

```
@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDrawEye()");

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    projection = eye.getPerspective(Z_NEAR, Z_FAR);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(view, 0, eye.getEyeView(), 0, camera, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelView, 0, view, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, projection, 0, modelView, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(lightPosInEyeSpace, 0, view, 0, lightPosInWorldSpace, 0);
    normalMatrix = RPMath.getNormalMatrix3x3(modelView);

    draw();
}
```

private void draw():

```
private void draw() {
    Log.i(TAG, "draw()");

    // Bind shader program, VBO and IBO.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramHandle);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboHandle);

    // Set vertex shader uniforms.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewProjectionParam, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewParam, 1, false, modelView, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixParam, 1, false, normalMatrix, 0);
    if(boolPhongLightning) { // fragment shader uniforms.
        vec = new float[3];
        vec[0] = lightPosInEyeSpace[0];
        vec[1] = lightPosInEyeSpace[1];
        vec[2] = lightPosInEyeSpace[2];
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(lightPosParam, 1, vec, 0);
    }

    // Set vertex attribute pointers.
    attribOffset = 0;
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionParam, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, attribStride, attribOffset);
    if(boolTexCoords) {
        attribOffset += 4 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordParam, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, attribStride, attribOffset);
    }
    attribOffset += 4 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalParam, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, attribStride, attribOffset);

    // Enable vertex attribute arrays.
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionParam);
    if(boolTexCoords) {
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordParam);
    }
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalParam);

    // Draw.
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, iboLength, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Disable vertex attribute arrays.
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionParam);
    if(boolTexCoords) {
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordParam);
    }
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalParam);

    // Unbind shader program, VBO and IBO.
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Class RPVBO and RPIBO. The interesting parts are the init() methods:

```
public final class RPVBO {

    private static final String TAG = "RPVBO";
    private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;

    private int[] vboHandles;
    private Vector<Float> vertices;
    private int vboLength;


    public RPVBO() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Constructor()");
        vboHandles = null;
        vertices = new Vector();
        vboLength = 0;
    }


    public void init() {
        Log.i(TAG, "init()");

        if((vboHandles != null) && (vboHandles[0] != 0)) {
            return;
        }

        vboHandles = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vboHandles, 0);

        if(vboHandles[0] != 0) {
            float[] vertexArray = getVertexArray();

            FloatBuffer clientSideBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexArray.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            clientSideBuffer.position(0);
            clientSideBuffer.put(vertexArray);
            clientSideBuffer.position(0);

            if(clientSideBuffer.capacity() != vertexArray.length) {
                Log.e(TAG, "init(): Error creating client side Floatbuffer.");
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + TAG + "init(): Error creating client side Floatbuffer.");
            }

            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[0]);

            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, clientSideBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, clientSideBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            MainActivity.checkGLError(TAG, "init(): glBufferData()");

            int[] params = new int[2];
            GLES20.glGetBufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLES20.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, params, 0);
            MainActivity.checkGLError(TAG, "init(): glGetBufferParameteriv()");
            GLES20.glGetBufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLES20.GL_BUFFER_USAGE, params, 1);
            MainActivity.checkGLError(TAG, "init(): glGetBufferParameteriv()");

            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            if(params[0] != (clientSideBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "init(): Error setting OpenGL VBO data.");
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + TAG + ": init(): Error setting OpenGL VBO data.");
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL VBO handle: " + vboHandles[0]);
            Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL VBO size in Bytes: " + params[0]);
            switch(params[1]) {
                case GLES20.GL_STREAM_DRAW:
                    Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL VBO usage: GL_STREAM_DRAW.");
                    break;

                case GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW:
                    Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL VBO usage: GL_STATIC_DRAW.");
                    break;

                case GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW:
                    Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL VBO usage: GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.");
            }

            vertices.clear();
        }

        if(vboHandles[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "init(): Error creating VBO in OpenGL.");
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + TAG + "init(): Error creating VBO in OpenGL.");
        }
    }


    public void addValue(final float value) {
        vertices.add(value);
        ++vboLength;
    }

    public void addValue(final Float value) {
        vertices.add(value);
        ++vboLength;
    }


    public void addArray(final float[] array) {
        final int arrayLength = array.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            vertices.add(array[i]);
            ++vboLength;
        }
    }

    public void addArray(final Float[] array) {
        final int arrayLength = array.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            vertices.add(array[i]);
            ++vboLength;
        }
    }


    public int getVboHandle() {
        if(vboHandles == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return vboHandles[0];
    }
    @Nullable
    public float[] getVertexArray() {
        float[] array = new float[vertices.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = vertices.get(i);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public int getVboLength() {
        return vboLength;
    }
}
```

```
public final class RPIBO {

    private static final String TAG = "RPIBO";
    private static final int BYTES_PER_SHORT = 2;

    private int[] iboHandles;
    private Vector<Short> indices;
    private int iboLength;


    public RPIBO() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Constructor()");
        iboHandles = null;
        indices = new Vector();
        iboLength = 0;
    }


    public void init() {
        Log.i(TAG, "init()");

        if((iboHandles != null) && (iboHandles[0] != 0)) {
            return;
        }

        iboHandles = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, iboHandles, 0);

        if(iboHandles[0] != 0) {
            short[] indexArray = getIndexArray();

            ShortBuffer clientSideBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indexArray.length * BYTES_PER_SHORT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
            clientSideBuffer.position(0);
            clientSideBuffer.put(indexArray);
            clientSideBuffer.position(0);

            if(clientSideBuffer.capacity() != indexArray.length) {
                Log.e(TAG, "init(): Error creating client side Shortbuffer.");
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + TAG + "init(): Error creating client side Shortbuffer.");
            }

            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboHandles[0]);

            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, clientSideBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_SHORT, clientSideBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            MainActivity.checkGLError(TAG, "init(): glBufferData()");

            int[] params = new int[2];
            GLES20.glGetBufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLES20.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, params, 0);
            MainActivity.checkGLError(TAG, "init(): glGetBufferParameteriv()");
            GLES20.glGetBufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLES20.GL_BUFFER_USAGE, params, 1);
            MainActivity.checkGLError(TAG, "init(): glGetBufferParameteriv()");

            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            if(params[0] != (clientSideBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_SHORT)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "init(): Error setting OpenGL IBO data.");
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + TAG + ": init(): Error setting OpenGL IBO data.");
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL IBO handle: " + iboHandles[0]);
            Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL IBO size in Bytes: " + params[0]);
            switch(params[1]) {
                case GLES20.GL_STREAM_DRAW:
                    Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL IBO usage: GL_STREAM_DRAW.");
                    break;

                case GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW:
                    Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL IBO usage: GL_STATIC_DRAW.");
                    break;

                case GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW:
                    Log.i(TAG, "init(): OpenGL IBO usage: GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.");
            }

            indices.clear();
        }

        if(iboHandles[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "init(): Error creating IBO in OpenGL.");
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + TAG + "init(): Error creating IBO in OpenGL.");
        }
    }


    public void addValue(final short value) {
        indices.add(value);
        ++iboLength;
    }

    public void addValue(final Short value) {
        indices.add(value);
        ++iboLength;
    }


    public void addArray(final short[] array) {
        final int arrayLength = array.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            indices.add(array[i]);
            ++iboLength;
        }
    }

    public void addArray(final Short[] array) {
        final int arrayLength = array.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            indices.add(array[i]);
            ++iboLength;
        }
    }


    public int getIboHandle() {
        if(iboHandles == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return iboHandles[0];
    }
    @Nullable
    public short[] getIndexArray() {
        short[] array = new short[indices.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = indices.get(i);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public int getIboLength() {
        return iboLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. iboLength is the number of indices.
I have also tried it with switching iboLength with the constant 36. It didnt change anything...

Comment: `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` didn't change anything either...

Comment: I have added the classes `RPVBO` and `RPIBO` to the question. Sorry for the two brackets outside of the code area.

Comment: My parser produces a packed vertex buffer array with homogeneous coordinates:
v1, v2, v3, 1.0, vt1, vt2, 1.0, 1.0, vn1, vn2, vn3, 1.0

So it always should be 4 right? 

I've just noticed that I need a boolean for the normals too. But in this case it shouldn't be a problem. The .obj file includes positions and normals. But no texture coordinates.

Comment: `attribStride` is 16. In my case the VBO consists of: v1, v2, v3, 1.0, vn1, vn2, vn3, 1.0. Should `attribStride` be 48?

Comment: Ohhhh man. I misunderstood `attribStride`. I thought that it would be from the end of the first attribute to the beginning of the second attribute. Now it works. THANKS!!! :D
So now it is:
`attribStride = 4 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
 if(boolTexCoords) attribStride += 4 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
 if(boolNormals) attribStride += 4 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (`stride`), specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes.

See the [Khronos OpenGL specification - Chapter 10.3. VERTEX ARRAYS](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), which says:

> When sourcing vertex data from the buffer object, `offset` specifies the offset in basic machine units of the first element in the vertex buffer. Pointers to the *i*th and `(i + 1)`st elements of the array differ by `stride` basic machine units, the pointer to the `(i + 1)`st element being greater.

This means, if your vertex buffer contains vertices, texture coordinates and normal vectors, in the format:

```
vx, vy, vz, 1.0,  s, t, 0.0, 1.0,  nx, ny, nz, 1.0
```

then `stride` has to be `(4+4+4)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 48`, because the size of the vertices is `4`, the size of the texture coordinates is `4` and the size of the normal vectors is `4`.
The `offset` of the texture coordinates is `4*BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 16` and the offset of the normal vector is `(4+4)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 32`.